# Monotonicity of little lp space.

Tags: real-analysis

I would like to show that for a sequence in $\mathscr l_1$ ,  square sum of the absolute value is equal to or less than the sum of the absolute value.

I tried Holder ineq  but it surely fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct inequality is $(\sum |a_n|^{2})^{1/2} \leq \sum |a_n|$. (With out the square root on the left the inequality is false). For a proof denote the right side by $r$ and let $b_n=\frac {a_n} r$. Then $\sum |b_n|=1$. This implies $|b_n| \leq 1 $ for all $n$. Hence $|b_n|^{2} \leq |b_n|$ and $(\sum |b_n|^{2})^{1/2} \leq \sum |b_n|=1$. Writing $b_n$ as $\frac {a_n} r$ we get the result.